# React.js: Collapsing all descendants nodes in tree, if the parent node collapse

Tags: treeview, reactjs

I create a tree node component.

I want to make such a behavior of node in which, in the case of the parent node collapse, collapsed and children. If a parent expand again, children will be collapsed still. How to do this?

Code example: http://jsbin.com/wuxutaqona/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Parent Node could have an extra state called parentChangeToCollapsed, which is only set in titleClickHandle function to true when parent change from opened to collapse. Pass it to the child component by props in the map function.
In the child Node component, getInitialState() lifecycle. Do the following

```
getInitialState: function() {
  if(this.prop.parentChangeToCollapsed){
    return({hideChildren: true});
  } else {
    return({hideChildren: this.props.hideChildren});
  }
}
```